# Regex replace variables pointer replace

Tags: regex

i have a string like

```
<? if $items.var1.var2 == $items2.var1.var2 ?>
```

i want to replace the string that it looks like this

```
<? if $items->{var1}->{var2} == $items2->{var1}->{var2} ?>
```

So strings like that i want to replace not quoted '$items2.var1.var2' strings like  this

```
 <? if $items.var1.var2 == '$items2.var1.var2' ?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to replace dots/variables only if they are followed by an even number of quotes. In Python, for example:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\.(\w+)(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)", r"->{\1}",
...         "<? if $items.var1.var2 == '$items2.var1.var2' ?>")
"<? if $items->{var1}->{var2} == '$items2.var1.var2' ?>"
```

**Explanation:**

```
\.       # Match .
(\w+)    # Match an alnum word and capture it
(?=      # Assert that it's possible to match:
 (?:     # Match this (don't capture):
  [^']*' # Any number of non-quotes, followed by a '
  [^']*' # The same again
 )*      # any number of times, including 0
 [^']*   # Match any number of non-quotes 
 $       # until the end of the string.
)        # End of lookahead assertion.
```

Comment: That's where regular expressions are starting to not be the tool of choice, and where you need a parser. Alternatively, first match `<\?.*?\?>` and then apply the first regex to those matches.

Answer (score 0):

This works in perl:

```
$str =~ s/\.(?=(\w|\.)+(?!'|"|\.)\W)/->/g;
#explained:
$str =~ s/
        \.             #A literal .
        (?=            #Followed by
          (\w|\.)+     #More than one word char or literal .
          (?!'|"|\.)   #Terminated by a \W (non-word char) that's not ',", or .
          \W
        )
        /->/gx;
```

At least for your examples. http://codepad.org/a4L43hDr